# Running gulp in dreamhost VPS

Tags: gulp, vps, dreamhost

Since the last dreamhost update which banned VPS users from accessing root/administrator. I am wondering how to do i install GULP in my hosting as it looks like we need admin access to install that and which dreamhost clearly denies it to give access.

So the problem is there are several tasks i need on my server to accomplish via GULP.

Do we have any alternative/Solution to this problem? (except changing the hosting service :))

I'm fed up of not being able to implement my production code in production environment.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DreamHost VPS are managed servers, they try to strike a balance between giving more computing power and isolation to customers (as opposed to shared hosting) while taking some management burden off of customers hands. This results in a compromise where you don't have to care about the underlying OS and basic services at all, and focus on your applications... but you're limited somewhat to what you can install on the machine.

The good news is that you can manage npm packages as an unprivileged user. While I am not a node expert, I have managed to upgrade npm and install gulp and all dependencies on my local user.

I first created a new dir for my version of npm (`mkdir npm`) then set the npm prefix to it

`$ npm config set prefix ~/npm`

Then it's time to install a newer version of npm in that dir:

`$ npm install -g npm`

After that's done, update the $PATH variable in your .bash_profile and in the current session, too `export PATH="$HOME/npm/bin:$PATH"` and confirm with a `which npm` that the npm command bash will execute is `/home/$YOUR_VPS_USER/npm/bin/npm`.

Now you can install the rest:

```
npm install -g bower
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install -g gulp
npm install -g yo
```

If you need to have more power and accept the responsibilities of running an unmanaged server, DreamHost Cloud is more for you though.